# OBTENER CONTENIDO DE UN TextBox AGREGADO EN UN TabControl -> TabPage

Tags: c#

Buen día, aquí con una consulta, estoy realizando un programa donde se muestra un menú con las opciones **nueva pestaña**, **cargar archivo** y **guardar archivo**.

Al presionar *nueva pestaña* es posible crear una nueva pestaña como editor de texto (usando TabControl -> TabPage -> textBox), esto se puede realizar n veces.

Al presionar *Cargar Archivo* es posible cargar un archivo desde cualquier ruta de la computadora, a nuestra pestaña actual

Al presionar *Guardar Archivo* es posible guardar la información de la pestaña actual en cualquier ruta dentro de la computadora.

**Mi DUDA ES**: como puedo acceder al textBox para guardar el contenido de la pestaña actual. 
El código que he realizo es este: en una clase tengo:

```
class AreaDeTrabajo
    {
        ArrayList listaPestanya;
        TabControl contenedor;
        TabPage nuevaPestanya;
        TextBox nuevoAreaTexto;

        public AreaDeTrabajo()
        {
            listaPestanya = new ArrayList();
            contenedor = new TabControl();
            nuevaPestanya = new TabPage();
            nuevoAreaTexto = new TextBox();
            inicializar();
        }

        public void inicializar()
        {
            nuevoAreaTexto.AcceptsReturn = true;
            nuevoAreaTexto.AcceptsTab = true;
            nuevoAreaTexto.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            nuevoAreaTexto.Multiline = true;
            nuevoAreaTexto.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Both;
        }

        public void crearPestanya(TabControl contenedor, int conteo)
        {
            nuevaPestanya.Text = "TAB " + conteo;
            listaPestanya.Add(nuevaPestanya);
            contenedor.TabPages.Add(nuevaPestanya);
            contenedor.SelectedTab = nuevaPestanya;
            nuevaPestanya.Controls.Add(nuevoAreaTexto);
        }

        public string infoDeAreaDeTexto(TabControl contenedor)
        {
            nuevaPestanya = contenedor.SelectedTab; 
            //??????????
            return nuevoAreaTexto.Text;
        }

        //public string MessageText
        //{
        //    get { return this.nuevoAreaTexto.Text; }
        //    set { this.nuevoAreaTexto.Text = value; }
        //}

        public void cargaDeArchivo(TabControl contenedor, string leer)
        {
            nuevaPestanya = contenedor.SelectedTab;
            nuevaPestanya.Controls.Clear();
            nuevoAreaTexto.Text = leer;
            nuevaPestanya.Controls.Add(nuevoAreaTexto);
        }

    }
```

Y en el Form tengo esto..

```
 public partial class Planificador : Form
    {
        ArrayList listPestanya = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList datosAguardar = new ArrayList();
        int contP = 1;


        public Planificador()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CenterToScreen();
        }

        private void DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void NuevaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // NUEVA PESTANYA 
        {

            AreaDeTrabajo miArea = new AreaDeTrabajo();
            miArea.crearPestanya(tabView, contP);
            contP++;
        }

        private void CargarArchivoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // CARGAR ARCHIVO
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
                openFile.Filter = "Archivo LY (*.ly)|*.ly";
                openFile.Title = "Abrir";

                if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string leer = File.ReadAllText(openFile.FileName);
                    AreaDeTrabajo abrirDoc = new AreaDeTrabajo();
                    abrirDoc.cargaDeArchivo(tabView, leer);
                    Console.WriteLine("proceso finalizado ");
                }
                openFile.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("crear una pestanya ff");
                Console.WriteLine("crear una pestanya x)");
            }
        }

        private void GuardarArchivoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // GUARDAR ARCHIVO
        {
            try
            {
                SaveFileDialog guardarArchivo = new SaveFileDialog();
                guardarArchivo.Filter = "Archivo LY (*.ly)|*.ly";
                guardarArchivo.Title = "Guardar";

                if (guardarArchivo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(guardarArchivo.FileName))
                    {
                        TabPage current_tab = tabView.SelectedTab;
                        string txt = guardarArchivo.FileName;

                        StreamWriter textoaGuardar = File.CreateText(txt);
                        textoaGuardar.Write(current_tab.Container); // aqui ??? que coloco


                        Console.WriteLine(current_tab.Container);
                        textoaGuardar.Flush();
                        textoaGuardar.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine(txt);
                        MessageBox.Show("ARCHIVO GUARDADO EXITOSAMENTE");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string txt = guardarArchivo.FileName;
                        StreamWriter textoaGuardar = File.CreateText(txt);

                        AreaDeTrabajo miTexto = new AreaDeTrabajo();

                        string info = "como obtengo la informacion";//miTexto.MessageText;

                        textoaGuardar.Write(info); // para el doc nuevo.
                        Console.WriteLine("esto es lo que guardo?? " + info);

                        textoaGuardar.Flush();
                        textoaGuardar.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine(txt);
                        MessageBox.Show("ARCHIVO GUARDADO EXITOSAMENTE");
                    }
                }
                guardarArchivo.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error al gurdar " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("error al guardar nooo " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

AGRADECERÍA SU APOYO

Answer (score 0):

Yo plantearia lo siguiente:

Cada vez que se pulsa el boton guardar, buscar la pestaña activa con

```
TabControl.SelectedTab
```

Una vez obtienes la pestaña activa, si no sabes el Textbox (ya que igual lo creas en tiempo real=, lo puedes buscar de esta forma

```
foreach (Control ctrl in TabControl.Controls)
if (ctrl is TextBox)
   //Si entra, es que tienes tu TextBox
```

Ahora ya tienes el textbox, para poder guardar lo que contenga